# magento configurable product order report

Tags: magento, product

How do I run a report from the back end that outlines which simple products of a configurable product we are selling?

When we look at the Reports > Products Ordered we can see the configurable but we would like to know which colours and sizes we are selling.

Answer (score 0):

Aheadwork's Aheadmetrics offers this service to differentiate by wildcard (sku based).

Check out tutorials on reports if you wish to create your own, however, I can't really help much more than this as you haven't provided any basis for a report.